# Redirect ajax post action to some other actioin

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, redirect

I am using ajax post action. In this action i have used `HttpContext.User.Identity.Name` to get the user id. Based on the user id i get some records related to that user id in database and return that values through json type.

Sometimes session got expired, in this case the `HttpContext.User.Identity.Name` value became empty. If it is empty or null it will throw the exception.

So I need to null or empty check the `HttpContext.User.Identity.Name` value, if it is null or empty i need to redirect it to login page.

But redirecting action not works inside the ajax post action. how to solve this problem?

i need to authorize the ajax post action. Can any one give solution for that?

Regards,
Karthik.

Comment: i tried [Authorize] on top of action it didn't work. and also if identity = null RedirectToAction("Action", "Controller"); not working

Answer (score 3):

> But redirecting action not works inside the ajax post action. how to solve this problem?

You could start by decorating your controller action with the `[Authorize]` attribute. This ensures that only authenticated users can access it and you are guaranteed that inside `User.Identity.Name` will never be null:

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
    string username = User.Identity.Name; // this will never throw
    ...
    return Json(...);
}
```

then take a look at the [following blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/04/prevent-forms-authentication-login-page-redirect-when-you-donrsquot-want.aspx) by Phil Haack. Inside its post Phil presents a nice plugin that allows you to configure ASP.NET to send 401 HTTP status code when an AJAX request to a protected action is made. So in your jQuery code you could very easily detect this condition and redirect:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/SomeAction',
    type: 'POST',
    statusCode: {
        200: function (data) {
            alert('200: Authenticated');
            // Bind the JSON data to the UI
        },
        401: function (data) {
            // the user is not authenticated => redirect him to the login page
            window.location.href = '/login';
        }
    }
});
```

And of course to avoid writing this 401 condition in all your AJAX requests you could very easily use the global [`.ajaxError()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/) handler to centralize this redirection logic for all your AJAX requests in case of 401 status code returned by the server:

```
$(document).ajaxError(function(e, jqxhr, settings, exception) {
    if (jqxhr.status == 401) { // unauthorized
        window.location.href = '/login';
    }
});
```

and now your AJAX requests become pretty standard:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/SomeAction',
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data) {
        // do something with the data returned by the action
    }
});
```